# Tensorflow wide and deep model with giving AttributeError with different dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm using Kaggle [Rossmann dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/rossmann-store-sales) to train a wide and deep model. The code is very similar to one given in the tutorial. I'm only changing the data used for the modeling.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
"""Example code for TensorFlow Wide & Deep Tutorial using TF.Learn API."""
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import argparse
import shutil
import sys
import tempfile

import pandas as pd
from six.moves import urllib
import tensorflow as tf


CSV_COLUMNS = [
    'Store', 'DayOfWeek',  'Sales', 'Customers', 'Open', 'Promo',
    'StateHoliday', 'SchoolHoliday', 'StoreType', 'Assortment',
    'CompetitionDistance', 'trend', 'Max_TemperatureC', 'Mean_TemperatureC',
    'Min_TemperatureC', 'Max_Humidity', 'Mean_Humidity', 'Min_Humidity'
]

StateHoliday = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
    "StateHoliday", ["True", "False"])
StoreType = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
    "StoreType", ['c', 'a', 'd', 'b'])
Assortment = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
    "Assortment", ['c', 'a', 'b'])

CompetitionDistance = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(
    "CompetitionDistance", hash_bucket_size=1000)
Customers = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(
    "Customers", hash_bucket_size=1000)
Store = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket(
    "Store", hash_bucket_size=1000)

trend = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("trend")
Max_TemperatureC = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("Max_TemperatureC")
Mean_TemperatureC = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("Mean_TemperatureC")
Min_TemperatureC = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("Min_TemperatureC")
Max_Humidity = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("Max_Humidity")
Mean_Humidity = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("Mean_Humidity")
Min_Humidity = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("Min_Humidity")


crossed_columns = [

    tf.feature_column.crossed_column(
        ["Assortment", "StoreType"], hash_bucket_size=1000)
]

deep_columns = [
    tf.feature_column.indicator_column("DayOfWeek"),
    tf.feature_column.indicator_column("Open"),
    tf.feature_column.indicator_column("Promo"),
    tf.feature_column.indicator_column("StateHoliday"),
    tf.feature_column.indicator_column("SchoolHoliday"),
    tf.feature_column.indicator_column("StoreType"),
    tf.feature_column.indicator_column("Assortment"),
    # To show an example of embedding
    tf.feature_column.embedding_column("CompetitionDistance", dimension=8),
    tf.feature_column.embedding_column("Customers", dimension=8),
    tf.feature_column.embedding_column("Store", dimension=8),
    trend,
    Max_TemperatureC,
    Mean_TemperatureC,
    Min_TemperatureC,
    Max_Humidity,
    Mean_Humidity,
    Min_Humidity
]


def build_estimator(model_dir):
    """Build an estimator."""

    m = tf.estimator.DNNLinearCombinedClassifier(
        model_dir=model_dir,
        linear_feature_columns=crossed_columns,
        dnn_feature_columns=deep_columns,
        dnn_hidden_units=[100, 50])
    return m


def input_fn(data_file, num_epochs, shuffle):
    df_data = pd.read_csv(
        "D:/Rossmann/Rossmann_Data/" + data_file + ".csv",
        names=CSV_COLUMNS,
        skipinitialspace=True,
        engine="python",
        skiprows=1)

    # remove NaN elements
    df_data = df_data.dropna(how="any", axis=0)
    print(df_data.dtypes)
    df_data = df_data.sort(['Sales'], ascending=[True])
    labels = df_data["Sales"].apply(lambda x: 1 if x >= 20000 else 0)

    return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
        x=df_data,
        y=labels,
        batch_size=100,
        num_epochs=num_epochs,
        shuffle=shuffle,
        num_threads=5)


model_dir = "D:/Rossmann/Rossmann_Data"

m = build_estimator(model_dir)

m.train(
    input_fn=input_fn("df1", num_epochs=None, shuffle=True),
    steps=2000)
```

But unfortunately I'm getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "timeSeriesPredictionUsingEmbedding2.py", line 121, in <module>
    steps=2000)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 241, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn=input_fn, hooks=hooks)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 630, in _train_model
    model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 615, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\canned\dnn_linear_combined.py", line 395, in _model_fn
    config=config)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\canned\dnn_linear_combined.py", line 156, in _dnn_linear_combined_model_fn
    feature_columns=dnn_feature_columns)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column.py", line 207, in input_layer
    _check_feature_columns(feature_columns)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column.py", line 1662, in _check_feature_columns
    if column.name in name_to_column:
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column.py", line 2453, in name
    return '{}_indicator'.format(self.categorical_column.name)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Can you please guide me where I'm getting this error? When I'm running your code, it's working perfectly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that [`tf.feature_column.indicator_column`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/indicator_column) accepts a categorical column instance, not column name ("DayOfWeek", "Open", etc). Probably this API looked differently in the previous tf versions, I'm not sure, but now you have to create a `categorical_column_*` and then wrap with an indicator.

By the way, I see you are using `DataFrame.sort` - this method has been deprecated and no longer works with the latest `pandas`. Use `sort_values`.

**Update**

I didn't notice that the code is an adaptation of a [tutorial example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/examples/learn/wide_n_deep_tutorial.py), that's why it deliberately uses all possible feature types, hashing, embedding, cross columns. Usually, one doesn't have to use all of them at once, in particular it's not necessary for Rossmann data. You *can* further add, for example, crossed columns, if you notice feature correlation in data, but just to get started, the data is mostly `numeric_column`s and few `categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list`s.

Here's my *complete* version of this code:

```
"""Example code for TensorFlow Wide & Deep Tutorial using TF.Learn API."""
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

CSV_COLUMNS = [
  'Store', 'DayOfWeek', 'Sales', 'Customers', 'Open', 'Promo',
  'StateHoliday', 'SchoolHoliday', 'StoreType', 'Assortment',
  'CompetitionDistance', 'trend', 'Max_TemperatureC', 'Mean_TemperatureC',
  'Min_TemperatureC', 'Max_Humidity', 'Mean_Humidity', 'Min_Humidity'
]

Store = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("Store")
DayOfWeek = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("DayOfWeek")
Customers = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("Customers")
Open = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("Open")
Promo = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("Promo")
StateHoliday = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list("StateHoliday", ["True", "False"])
SchoolHoliday = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("SchoolHoliday")
StoreType = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list("StoreType", ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
Assortment = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list("Assortment", ['a', 'b', 'c'])
CompetitionDistance = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("CompetitionDistance")
trend = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("trend")
Max_TemperatureC = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("Max_TemperatureC")
Mean_TemperatureC = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("Mean_TemperatureC")
Min_TemperatureC = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("Min_TemperatureC")
Max_Humidity = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("Max_Humidity")
Mean_Humidity = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("Mean_Humidity")
Min_Humidity = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("Min_Humidity")

deep_columns = [
  Store,
  DayOfWeek,
  Customers,
  Open,
  Promo,
  tf.feature_column.indicator_column(StateHoliday),
  SchoolHoliday,
  tf.feature_column.indicator_column(StoreType),
  tf.feature_column.indicator_column(Assortment),
  CompetitionDistance,
  trend,
  Max_TemperatureC,
  Mean_TemperatureC,
  Min_TemperatureC,
  Max_Humidity,
  Mean_Humidity,
  Min_Humidity
]


def build_estimator(model_dir):
  """Build an estimator."""
  return tf.estimator.DNNLinearCombinedClassifier(
    model_dir=model_dir,
    dnn_feature_columns=deep_columns,
    dnn_hidden_units=[100, 50])


def input_fn(data_file, num_epochs, shuffle):
  df_data = pd.read_csv(data_file + ".csv",
                        names=CSV_COLUMNS,
                        dtype={"StateHoliday": str},
                        skipinitialspace=True,
                        engine="python",
                        skiprows=1)

  # remove NaN elements
  df_data = df_data.dropna(how="any", axis=0)
  df_data = df_data.sort_values(['Sales'], ascending=[True])
  labels = df_data["Sales"].apply(lambda x: 1 if x >= 20000 else 0)

  return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
    x=df_data,
    y=labels,
    batch_size=100,
    num_epochs=num_epochs,
    shuffle=shuffle,
    num_threads=5)


m = build_estimator(model_dir="./model")
m.train(input_fn=input_fn("df1", num_epochs=None, shuffle=True),
        steps=2000)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can you please show me how to use `categorical_column_*`. I tried `tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_hash_bucket`, as I did for store, for all categorical variables. And then just calling the  `tf.feature_column.indicator_column`. But still I'm getting the same error. Thanks!

Comment: I could run my code if I remove `tf.feature_column.indicator_column` part. So your answer solve part of my problem in the sense that I know why the issue was coming. But it will be very helpful, if you can suggest me how I can modify the `tf.feature_column.indicator_column ` so that I can use numeric categorical variables. Else I'll mark your answer as answered. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Beta I have updated my answer with a complete working example. I simplified most of the columns, because it doesn't look like complications are really necessary for this data set. In particular, there's a usage of `indicator_column` with `categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list`

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are awesome!!